# Is flying an RC aircraft and selling the results of that flight "commercial" flight?

Tags: commerce

On the Aviation.SE someone asked about the legality of flying RC aircraft. The answers say that [commercial flights are verboten](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/12424/1838)

But what, precisely, makes it a commercial flight?

[This infographic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2852/1838) says:

> Don't fly model aircraft for payment or commercial purposes

I can think of a good example - say someone wanted news footage of  so they offered me $100 to fly a drone and take some video.

That seems like it would qualify for commercial purposes.

But what if I took a drone flight just for kicks and grins and while it was up  happened. If I sold the recording, would that be considered a commercial flight?

Alternatively, what if I took a drone flight *with the intention of selling the results of that flight*? (e.g. video or photos)